# i can't retrive an array from my database android

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, android-database

In my function to get stuff from a database containing an array, I can't find a method to get array:

```
public Meals getMeals(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
                        TABLE_MEALS, 
                        new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_CTRGRY, KEY_PIC, KEY_INGRDNTS}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Meals Meal = new Meals(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getInt(4), cursor./**placeholder for equivilant of getInt/String but for List<String>*/);
    // return Meals
    return Meal;
}
```

Comment: `public List<Meal> getMeals(int id)` and then return list of object Meal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to iterate cursor, and then get the attribute's value for each row. You can use following:

```
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
}

ArrayList<Meal> meals = new ArrayList();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Meal meal = new Meal();
    meal.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
    meal.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
    ... // set rest fields
    meals.add(meal);
}
return meals;
```

Comment: I hope this will help you.